# value cannot be null. parameter name path

Tags: c#, .net

I put a command line argument value `"1|2|c:\temp"` under properties-> debug box.

In my code I read data using

```
string[] args = Environment.CommandLine.Split('|').ToArray();
```

When I run application I get all argument value and working fine but when I run exe file I am getting

> value cannot be null. parameter name path

I searched google but did not get any idea of reason and how to solve that.

Code:

```
string[] args = Environment.CommandLine.Split('|').ToArray(); 

for (int i = 0; i < args.Count(); i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            this.ImageFilePath = args[i];
            break;
        case 3:
            this.ImageFileName = args[i];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Please give me solution or idea to resole error.

Comment: `string.Split` returns an array, so the `ToArray` is pointless.

Comment: How do you run exe? By double clicking on it you will not get the args and you're not handling empty args condition.

Comment: If you're running the exe file from the command line and you are trying to pass parameters using the pipe | symbol, that's actually used by the operating system for piping result of one command to another. Try a different character as a delimiter.

Comment: First of all show the code that s throwing the exception.  Nowhere in the code you posted is there a `path` parameter.

Comment: Plus your `for` statement is bizarre; why not just `this.ImageFilePath = args[2]; this.ImageFileName = args[3];`?

Comment: @DStanley While I don't approve of the design pattern, it is a somewhat common one to make sure you don't read beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @sheppe Good catch. I totally missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using the pipe character (`|`) in parameters to command-line utilities. If you do not enclose it in double quotes the executable will only receive part of the parameter. E.g.

```
test.exe this|is|a|test
```

... will only result in the parameter "this" being supplied to test.exe. The output of test.exe will then be piped into the application `is`, if it exists, and the output of that piped into application `a`, and so on...

On the other hand, this should do what you expect:

```
test.exe "this|is|a|test"
```

Personally, I would consider using an alternative separator character.

Comment: This is a more verbose version of what I said in the comments on the original question. It didn't seem "answer worthy" to me.

Comment: @sheppe Yep, I started writing it before you'd commented and I +1'd your comment after I'd posted the answer. Sometimes it helps to explain in full and I was bored :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for quick response. I will modify code according to your advice.

Comment: Shaharyar, yes I am double clicking exe file not run from command prompt with arguments. Ok. I will handle empty args but I do not put hard coded value in code if argument value is empty. How can I pass arguments when I double  click .exe file?       any idea or code

Comment: @Morshed You can create separate batch file scripts, use shortcut links, drag files onto the EXE... numerous ways but it depends on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @sheppe I handled empty argument value. I put  hard coded and I also change delimiter as "$"  character instead of pipe (|). Now, if I double click exe file I am getting "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array" error though I put 4 arguments and read exactly 4 arguments value. Another observation, I executed exe from command line with arguments e.g. text.exe 1$2$c:\temp\$test, it does not throw error. What is the solution if I double click exe file to get ride of  IndexOutOfRangeException?

Comment: @Morshed indexes in C# are zero-based. Change your for line to take that into account.

Change: for (int i = 0; i < args.Count(); i++)
To: for (int i = 0; i < args.Count() - 1; i++)

Comment: @sheppe I am still getting exception. I just got rid of for loop and used code follows for example string[] args = Environment.CommandLine.Split('$');

Comment: Code:string first = "", second="", third="", fourth = "";
                if (args != null && args.Count() > 0)
                {
                    first = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]) ? "1" : args[0];
                    second = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[1]) ? "2" : args[1];
                    third = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[2]) ? @"c:\\temp\" : args[2];
                    fourth = string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[3]) ? "test" : args[3];
                                        
                } .  i get exception when i double click my .exe file.